# How to use tinycthread to do C++ concurrent programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, tinycthread

I just started use tinycthread.h to do my concurrent programming. However, i got no ideas how to use it. Currently, i want to know how can I create a thread function with this library.

Here are two functions listed in the tinycthread library

```
typedef int(* thrd_start_t)(void *arg)
int thrd_create (thrd_t * thr,thrd_start_t func,void * arg )
```

I want to create a thread function with an integer as a parameter.

```
int Haha (int a){} ->  to be my thread function

int main(){
thrd_t t;
thrd_create(&t,Haha,int a);

}
```

I write something like this in my program.

but as the accepted `typedef int(* thrd_start_t)(void *arg)` of a typedef is in this way which does not allow me to put any integer as my parameters. So what should i do to create a thread function with an integer as a parameter.

Comment: Prefer standard `<thread>` header rather than 3rd party solutions.

Comment: Since you're using C++ maybe [TinyThread++](http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/) is better alternative?

Comment: In C++, you might want to check [this reference instead](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). The standard library FTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `Haha` must be `void *` not `int`, so try to pass your integer inputs by some casting:

```
int Haha (void *arg)
{
    int *a = static_cast<int*>(arg);

    printf("%d", *a);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int param = 123;

    thrd_t t;
    thrd_create(&t, Haha, &param);
    thrd_join(t, NULL);
}
```

Since [TinyCThread](http://tinycthread.bitsnbites.eu/) is C alternative of [TinyThread++](http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/), You should use that C++ class library.

Also, C++ supports [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am now using Visual studio to compile my code. However, it keeps on giving me an error unresolved external symbol "thrd_create". What should I do???

Answer (score 1):

Pass a pointer to an `int` variable holding the value you want to pass:

```
int a = 10;
thrd_create(&t, Haha, &a);
...

int Haha(void *ptr) {
   int *ap = static_cast<int*>(ptr);
   int a = *ap;

}
```

If you intend to write through the `ap` pointer, make sure the pointed at object didn't go out of scope.